# Button clicking twice

Tags: android, button

I have a problem with android, with a button. I programmed the
button like it was in the developer pages to display a text in a
textview when clicked, but when I run my application I have to press
my button twice to make it happen. I thought it might have something
to do with focus, but I'm not sure.

Also, when I apply a theme (see styles and themes) I even have to
press any button twice, not only the button stated above, but for
example also the 'yes' or 'no' button in the question to quit the
application (via a Dialog)

I searched forums for this, but didn't find
the answer I was looking for. Hopefully someone can provide me with an
idea.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);    

((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnZoeken)).setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    zoekOpPostcodes(txtZoeken.getText().toString());
                }

                private void zoekOpPostcodes(String zoekterm){

                                                //more irrelevant code
                                         txtResultaat.setText(txtRes);
                            }

//more irrelevant code
private void quit() {
    // prepare the alert box
    AlertDialog.Builder abQuit = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // set the message to display
    abQuit.setMessage("Weet je zeker dat je wil afsluiten?");

    // set a positive/yes button and create a listener
    abQuit.setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tot ziens!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            iRegionForAndroid.this.finish();
        }
    });

    // set a negative/no button and create a listener
    abQuit.setNegativeButton("Nee", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Afsluiten geannuleerd!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // display box
    abQuit.show();
```

}

If you need any more of my code for this, "ask and you shall receive" :)
seems to be something wrong with the "code" sections, it doensn't contain all the code, but portions of it under the "code" section

Comment: We're in need of code. I think you should assume we need and give us initially instead of waiting.

Comment: Is this happening in an emulator or an actual machine ? And yes, the code would be nice !

Comment: both emulator as actual machine

Answer (score 19):

You may be right about it being related to focus.

You might have android:focusableInTouchMode="true", and it needs to be false.  The first click focuses on the item, and the second one invokes the listener.

Comment: Thank you! I found this post while having the same problem in my app...I set framelayouts to act as buttons, and I had to double click them.   turns out I had focusable in touch mode turned on..disabled it and single clicks worked again.